# Проблема со структурой

Tags: c++, visual-c++, указатели

Есть структура

```
struct  Array
{
    int **m;
    int sizeX;
    int sizeY;
};
```

Есть функция

```
void input(Array *a)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < a->sizeX; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < a->sizeY; j++)
    {
            cout << "Input [" << i + 1 << ":" << j + 1 << "] element: ";
            cin >> a->m[i][j];
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < a->sizeX; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < a->sizeY; j++)
        cout << a->m[i][j];
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

И есть проблема: когда запускаю программу, вылетает ошибка. Отладчик MVS15 говорит, что проблема в элементе структуры `m`
Вот тело функции `main`

```
int main()
{
    Array *a = new Array;
    a->sizeX = 3;
    a->sizeY = 3;
    input(a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске отладчик говорит, что `m = 0xCEDECEDF` и программа зависает
Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатель `m` не инициализирован, а в функции `input` вы обращаетесь к этой переменной.

Попробуйте так:

```
Array *a = new Array;
a->sizeX = 3;
a->sizeY = 3;
// Инициализация двумерного массива.
a->m = new int*[a->sizeX];
for (int i = 0; i < a->sizeX; ++i) {
   a->m[i] = new int[a->sizeY];
}
input(a);
```

И не забудьте освободить динамически выделенную память.

Answer (score 0):

Указателю `m` нигде не присваивается значение.